# How to calculate constant acceleration required to move an object by a distance $d$ in time $t$?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, simulations, software

I’m working on an animation software and I require objects to have a downward acceleration. They currently fall at a constant velocity but I want to make them accelerate to make the animation look more dynamic. I’m unable to figure out the math required to calculate a constant acceleration that would make the object successfully complete the distance in the same amount of time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration

Comment: I actually did read the equations of motion earlier. Although I’m finding myself quite confused still. Let’s say my object starts at position 0 and time 0 and has to reach a point at position 200 in 25 seconds. The velocity then becomes 40 pixels per second. So what would be the ideal rate for the same object if it were to consistently accelerate at that rate to reach position 200 in 25 seconds?

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for calculations like that are off-topic here. We prefer conceptual questions over calculations. But you should be able to use those equations and algebra to solve. $s_0=0$, $s=200$, $v_0=0$, $t=25$.

Comment: Oh I’m sorry. I didn’t really want an answer to that calculation but I merely used it as an example to explain my conceptual confusion. I’ll look into the equations with more detail though! Thanks

Comment: Let me suggest that you go to the YouTube channel Let's Code Physics. I believe you will find everything you need there, accelerated motion equations plus some animations in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the equation of motion
$$v=u+at$$
$$v^2=u^2+2as$$
In your case $a\rightarrow -a$ and $v=0$ so that
$$a=\frac{u}{t} \ \ \& \ \  u^2=2as$$
$$a=\frac{\sqrt{2as}}{t}\Rightarrow \boxed{a=\frac{2s}{t}}$$

---

Note that you have to put a condition so that when the particle has position $d$ its acceleration is set to $0$ otherwise the particle gets backward due to acceleration.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll plug this into the simulator soon.